# Warp Shadow - CSS

Tags: html, css, css3

estou tentando fazer um efeito de warp shadow em minha div mas não estou conseguindo, alguem pode me ajudar?

www.planow.com.br/nobre/empresa.php

Comment: poste o seu código, o que fez até agora, fica mais fácil de ajudar!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/95bb3f2885cf8733090e

Comment: Coloque o código na pergunta, para que os OP possam ter o conteúdo necessário para responder na pergunta. Na dúvida veja [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que o que esteja procurando seja isto

***HTML***

```
<div class="box boxColor shadow_box">
    Warp Shadow
    <span class="warp"></span>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.box {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}

.boxColor {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#FFDB4D), to(#EABB00));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFDB4D, #EABB00);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFDB4D, #EABB00);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFDB4D, #EABB00);
    background: linear-gradient(#FFDB4D, #EABB00);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=’#FFDB4D’, endColorstr=’#EABB00′);
}

.shadow_box {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #9C9C9C;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #9C9C9C;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #9C9C9C;
    position: relative;
}

.shadow_box span.warp {
    width: 100%;
    height: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -26px;
    right: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px -10px 5px #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -10px 5px #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -10px 5px #fff;
    border-radius: 50% / 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50% / 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 400px 20px;
}
```

Pode acompanhar o resultado nesta **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/nJLqt/)**

Fonte: [Wrap Shadow with CSS3](http://lokeshkhinchi.wordpress.com/2010/12/10/warp-shadow-using-css-3/)

Comment: valew. isso mesmo